# Transparent UIPopover

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uipopovercontroller

Is there a way to make the UIPopOver transparent (alpha = 0.75 or so). Unfortunately there is no alpha property for UIPopOver. I need to present a popover so that the view beneath it will still be partially visible. Any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
popoverController.contentViewController.view.alpha = 0.5;
```

alpha is an property of an UIView so you need to get the view of the popOver and then set the alpha to that view.

Comment: while this should work in theory, in reality it will not work.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with iOS5.0, one can provide a custom background for the `UIPopoverController`. That background has to be derived from `UIPopoverBackgroundView` which does provide the normal `UIView` properties like `alpha`. 
Note that the name is a bit confusing - the `UIPopoverBackgroundView` provides the frame-, the arrow- as well as the background-graphics.

So if you need an entirely semi-transparent `UIPopoverController`, all you have to do is supply a `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class which sets its `alpha` towards something below `1.0`. You will also need to make sure that your contentViewController's view is (fully) transparent.

Example:

[image]

---

For details, [see the `popoverBackgroundViewClass` property of `UIPopoverController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/popoverBackgroundViewClass):

```
popoverBackgroundViewClass
```

> The class to use for displaying the popover background content.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) Class popoverBackgroundViewClass
```

**Discussion**

> The default value of this property is nil, which indicates that the
>   popover controller should use the default popover appearance. Setting
>   this property to a value other than nil causes the popover controller
>   to use the specified class to draw the popover’s background content.
>   The class you specify must be a subclass of UIPopoverBackgroundView.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared In
UIPopoverController.h

Comment: Havent used it yet but good to see there is finally more to customize of a UIPopover

Comment: This support was deprecated in iOS 9.0.  Don't suppose anyone knows if there is a newer way?

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 13:

There seems to be an opaque subview with a dark gray background of type *_UIPopoverStandardChromeView* with no API means for controlling it (Apple bug?). To make the popover transparent, you may needed to the add the hack below to the presented view controller. It must be done in or after the *viewDidAppear(_:)* call. It didn't work in *viewWillAppear(_:)* or earlier calls.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Only works in viewDidAppear()
    self.popoverPresentationController?.containerView?.subviews.last?.subviews.first?.alpha = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I spent hours trying to figure this out and saw your answer as I discovered it myself in the view hierarchy tool. In addition, I got this to work in viewDidLayoutSubviews!

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no property to set the alpha of a `UIPopoverController`.

If you do:    `popoverController.contentViewController.view.alpha = 0.5;`

The inside view & content will be transparant and not the `UIPopoverController` itself.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417179/ios-uipopovercontroller-transparency-alpha)

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the backgroundColour property of the popoverPresentationController to do this, e.g.

```
            if let popoverPresentationController = myController.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            }
```

(don't forget to set the view in the popover and controls in that view to transparent as well as appropriate to the effect you are trying to acheive)

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20011242/2466193) for more details.