# How to set clearColor for UIPopover View?

Tags: ios, iphone, uipopovercontroller

I need to set `UIPopover` background color to `clearColor`. But rest of all colors are working fine with below code:

```
myPopover.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

but when I set `clearColor`, there is a white background instead of transparent.
Can any one help me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Whats background color of your parent view on which you are calling popOver view

Comment: @walle84: You are asking about contentViewController of popOver?

Comment: There is a parent view on which we present the popOver view so check wts background color of your parent View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're talking about is a UIPopoverController, then try setting the background color to its content view controller's view.

`myPopover.contentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Also, check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14917336/1001803) about custom popover backgrounds.

Comment: I changed content view background color. But still same effect. I set content view background and popovercolroller background to clearColor, still i don't get transparent background.

Comment: Its worked when i used popoverBackgroundViewClass property. Thanks!