# UIPopoverPresentationController without overlay

Tags: swift, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I am implementing a popover view using UIPopoverPresentationController.

[image]

The trouble with this, is that by default, I have a shadow with a large radius for the controller.

I want to disable this  - the overlay.

I have tried:

1. to customise the layout shadow (using a UIPopoverBackgroundView):

   ```
   layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.01).cgColor
   layer.shadowOffset = .zero
   layer.shadowRadius = 0
   ```
2. In view debugging - I can see behind the popup 4 image views with gray gradient background:

[image]

I am sure this is a default behaviour, of showing an overlay behind a popover.

How do disable this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678456/transparent-uipopover?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697436/how-can-i-change-the-opacity-of-the-overlay-behind-uipopoverpresentationcontroll/). But those didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look at the views hierarchy you will notice that the shadow layer _UIMirrorNinePatchView is a sublayer of UITransitionView same as UIPopoverView - both are on the same level.

[views hierarchy picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TYYX.png)

In this case you can try to hide this sublayer like so:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let shadowLayer = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.layer.sublayers?[1].sublayers?[1] {
        shadowLayer.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Make sure to hide it in viewDidLayoutSubviews to avoid exceptions related to missing sublayers or sublayer flickering.

Comment: I didn't liked this solution, because it uses a UIApplication, and it has an ugly method of finding out that view. I was applying this to my app. It does work, although I can see some flickering. At the moment, I don't have another solution to this. @kpoznak, thanks