# Popover ViewController with transparency?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have been trying to figure out how to create a popover view or view controller (not sure which one to use) over my main view controller. I want the popover to act how the device notification center window acts. I don't necessarily want it to be a drag down, but when I click a button I want the window to display over the whole main view controller with a slightly transparent view similar to the notification center. The idea is, I would like to see the "blurred" content through the new window. Any ideas on what I should do to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize / style a UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552686/how-to-customize-style-a-uipopovercontroller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent UIPopover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678456/transparent-uipopover)

Answer (score -3):

When you present a `UIViewController` (yourVC) with a `modalPresentationStyle = .Popover`, UIKit creates an instance of the `UIPopoverPresentationController` class automatically.   You can set properties for this view controller as `yourVC.popoverPresentationController?`.

If you set `yourVC.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`, then you will get a transparent blur effect.

Good explanation can be found in Apple's documentation for `UIPopoeverPresentationController`.