# Customizing the UIPopoverController view background and border color

Tags: ios, ipad, popover

Is it possible to change the border color, navigation bar style/color, and arrow style/color of a pop over view? If so, how? If some sample code is available, then that'll be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `UIPopoverController` is not customizable like that. You can't change the border color, navigation bar style/color, or arrow style/color: [How to customize / style a UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552686/how-to-customize-style-a-uipopovercontroller).

Comment: This is no longer valid, after iOS5 popoverBackgroundView can be subclassed, here is a good one I have just used: https://github.com/GiK/GIKPopoverBackgroundView

Comment: Note- above one is old/outdated answer. Now in iOS 7, for navigation bar and arrow color changes, `UIPopoverController` has introduced `backgroundColor` as property. See my answer below.

Answer (score 43):

iOS 7 onwards, you can change `backgroundColor` of `UIPopoverController` which affects the navigation background color as well as arrows of popover.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Usage example:

```
    if ([self.popoverVC respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {   // Check to avoid app crash prior to iOS 7
        self.popoverVC.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
```

**Note** - As of now (iOS 7.0.3), in some cases (like set color using colorWithPatternImage:), the simulator doesn't honor the color but *on device it works fine*.

Comment: Yep, if you only need to change the background of the popover (including the arrow), this is the quickest way to do it.  Much better than subclassing `UIPopoverBackgroundView` for a simple change.

Comment: Note that if the view you're displaying inside the popover has its own background color, you will only see the popover's background color on the arrow.

Comment: For simple customizations (IE changing arrow color) this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

Now in iOS 5, popoverBackgroundViewClass is available.

Answer (score 1):

From ios 5 onward you can do much just try this library https://github.com/ddebin/DDPopoverBackgroundView
you can customise border tint color, bodrer width as well as arrow

look at the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar and tool bar inside a popover are just a standard UINavigationBar and UIToolBar, I've had success in changing their appearance just as you would with a normal nav bar or tool bar. The border however is not easily customizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ElegantPopover](https://github.com/prasad1120/ElegantPopover) cocoapod to accomplish some of that.

Answer (score -2):

I try to trick it by customizing the viewcontroller inside the popover and then hiding the popover border using this code

```
UIView * border = [[insideViewController.view.superview.superview.superview subviews] objectAtIndex:0];  
border.hidden = YES;
```

The app is actually still in development so I'm hoping other people will comment on this solution.

Comment: Modifying the unexposed view hierarchy is probably a bad idea, even if your app is accepted. Should the view be modified by Apple in the future, your code would suddenly stop working.

Comment: You might want to link to your dup answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7063257/1015071