# ios how to change alpha of popover presentation controller layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I'm quite new in ios programming so sorry if I ask a dumb questin.

I want to develop an application for **ipad using ios 7.1**.

**My problem:**
I used popoover presentation from storyboard to link a button to a view controller. I gave a custom class for the view controller that will be poppedover. But initially I want to **set its layout alpha value** and afterwards to make an animation. I did something like this:

```
self.view.alpha = 0.2;
self.popoverPresentationController.containerView.alpha = 0.2;
```

But I'm getting an **error** when I use the second line: 
**[Popover popoverPresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance..**.

So how can I change my popover alpha value at runtime? Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UIPopoverController transparency / alpha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417179/ios-uipopovercontroller-transparency-alpha)

Comment: Do you want to a transparent background or you want it to have a bit transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the property .popoverPresentationController is available for iOS 8.0 and later, so that's why you are getting the error message.
Regarding the alpha transparency, you can find answer in the comments.