# How to change border color in UIPopOver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

How to change color for popup border in iPad application? I change style in all elements of application but can't on popup.
[image]

Comment: I guess [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552686/how-to-customize-style-a-uipopovercontroller) could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at how it is done in [WEPopover](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover). This is a custom implementation of a pop over menu, since any customization of `UIPopOver` seems difficult to attain without using private API.